# How to Unmarshal a Json Array in Go

Tags: json, go

I'm struggling to parse the following json data:

```
[{"id":90129966,"from":"user@admin.com","subject":"golang test","date":"2020-10-20 07:39:55"}]
```

Here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type JsonTemplate struct {
    Id      int    `json:"id"`
    From    string `json:"from"`
    Subject string `json:"subject"`
    Date    string `json:"date"`
}

type Response struct {
    JsonTemplate []JsonTemplate
}


func main() {

    mockJson := `[{"id":90129966,"from":"user@admin.com","subject":"golang test","date":"2020-10-20 07:39:55"}]`

    var response Response

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(mockJson), &response)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(response)
}
```

The output:

```
json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type main.Response
{[]}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: use `var response []JsonTemplate`

Comment: Ah interesting. Thanks Flimzy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer from Flimzy: `var response []JsonTemplate`. Thanks again.